# How to create trending list with hashtags and mention list with twitter IDs like @xyz

Tags: c#, .net, regex, wpf

I am struggling to create a trending list with hashtags and mention list with twitter IDs at once. I have one textbox, one button and two list views. As soon as I enter #abc with some text in textbox and press button, the #abc moves to list view to show that the hashtag is creating trending list, but I am unable to do it for Twitter IDs. This will be ideal if both hashtags and twitter IDs work the same time from a text box. E.g if I write `Hiya please see #helloworld and how about @xyz` and press button, both will move to their respective list views. Following is the code for the hashtag. Can someone help me with how to do it for Twitter IDs? Many thanks.

```
 private void buttonTwitter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=#)\w+");
        var matches = regex.Matches(tweetMsgsTextBox.Text);

        foreach (Match m in matches)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hurray!! Hash Tag is on Trending!");

            listhtag.Items.Add ("#" + m.Value);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your click handler to this updated regex pattern

```
Regex.Matches("Hiya please see #helloworld and how about @xyz", @"([#@]\w+)")
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select (mt => mt.Groups[0].Value )
     .ToList()
     .ForEach( itm => listhtag.Items.Add(itm));
```

The pattern `([#@]\w+)` will capture either a "#" or a "@" and then the word which follows *as an individual match*. Then extract from each match that match group capture and place it into the list.

---

If you have a different lists, then check the first character and add it to the appropriate list in your foreach operation.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Just a little query remaining, how to add #helloworld in separate list view 1 and @xyz in list view 2? Which will make one list view for Trending and one for mentions. Thanks in advance.